# is there a way to define a group of buttons by once

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm building a mine cleaner game that contains 49 buttons, the user clicks one of the buttons and the program would look for the mines around or it would blow up

My question is, is there a way to define a group of buttons instead of annotating each one of them in the controller class?

```
    <Text text=" " GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
    <Text text=" 1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
    <Text text=" 2" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
    <Text text=" 3" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
    <Text text=" 4" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
    <Text text=" 5" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
    <Text text=" 6" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
    <Text text=" 7" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>

    <Text text="A" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="A1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="A2" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="A3" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="A4" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="A5" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="A6" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="A7" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

    <Text text="B" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="B1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="B2" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="B3" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="B4" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="B5" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="B6" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="B7" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>

    <Text text="C" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="3"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="C1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="C2" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="C3" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="C4" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="3"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="C5" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="3"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="C6" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="3"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="C7" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="3"/>

    <Text text="D" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="4"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="D1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="D2" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="D3" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="4"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="D4" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="4"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="D5" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="4"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="D6" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="4"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="D7" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="4"/>


    <Text text="E" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="5"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="E1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="E2" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="E3" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="5"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="E4" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="5"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="E5" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="5"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="E6" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="5"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="E7" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="5"/>

    <Text text="F" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="6"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="F1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="F2" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="6"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="F3" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="6"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="F4" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="6"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="F5" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="6"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="F6" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="6"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="F7" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="6"/>

    <Text text="G" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="7"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="G1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="G2" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="7"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="G3" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="7"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="G4" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="7"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="G5" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="7"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="G6" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="7"/>
    <Button text="*" fx:id="G7" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="7"/>
```

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class Controller {

```
@FXML
private Button A1;
@FXML
private Button A2;
@FXML
private Button A3;
@FXML
private Button A4;
@FXML
private Button A5;
@FXML
private Button A6;
@FXML
private Button A7;
@FXML
private Button B1;
@FXML
private Button B2;
@FXML
private Button B3;
@FXML
private Button B4;
@FXML
private Button B5;
@FXML
private Button B6;
@FXML
private Button B7;
@FXML
private Button C1;
@FXML
private Button C2;
@FXML
private Button C3;
@FXML
private Button C4;
@FXML
private Button C5;
@FXML
private Button C6;
@FXML
private Button C7;
@FXML
private Button E1;
@FXML
private Button E2;
@FXML
private Button E3;
@FXML
private Button E4;
@FXML
private Button E5;
@FXML
private Button E6;
@FXML
private Button E7;
@FXML
private Button F1;
@FXML
private Button F2;
@FXML
private Button F3;
@FXML
private Button F4;
@FXML
private Button F5;
@FXML
private Button F6;
@FXML
private Button F7;
@FXML
private Button G1;
@FXML
private Button G2;
@FXML
private Button G3;
@FXML
private Button G4;
@FXML
private Button G5;
@FXML
private Button G6;
@FXML
private Button G7;
```

}

Comment: `@FXML private Button a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7;`

Comment: If you're not opposed to initializing all of the buttons in code, you can make a 2D array and use a for loop to create them all.

Comment: use a collection for similar items.